Ng Serve compilation failed "Error: Maximum call stack size exceeded" in angular 18 upgradation

./src/main.ts - Error: Module build failed (from ./node_modules/@ngtools/webpack/src/ivy/index.js):
Error: Maximum call stack size exceeded
./src/polyfills.ts - Error: Module build failed (from ./node_modules/@ngtools/webpack/src/ivy/index.js):
Error: Maximum call stack size exceeded


Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.
